# Add breaks to text attribute in react-circular-progressbar

Tags: reactjs, text

I'm trying to add breaks to the text attribute in react-circular-progressbar. I added the CSS file the package told me to.

```
<CircularProgressbar
percentage={50}
text={`hello \n how are you`}
initialAnimation={true}
/>
```

I tried adding a \n to the text and can't add a space.

Heres an example on SandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vymm4oln6y

Heres the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a issue on Github regarding this, https://github.com/iqnivek/react-circular-progressbar/issues/44 where the author posted a solution for this issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/mzr5k37o6p

Answer (score 0):

all you need is Space HTML Character Entity.
Try this:

```
text='hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;how are you'
```

Comment: My bad i accidentally wrote spaces instead of breaks.